# Can i use a filter in J2EE to convert bytes from tiff to pdf?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, pdf, servlet-filters, tiff

I have a task to convert a TIFF to PDF based on a flag condition. Now the tiff file is stored at the server end. When the client (browser) clicks on downloading this file, the bytes are read from the server and transmitted using `BufferedOutputStream`
I can call Linux command line utility `tiff2pdf` through java code and then transmit those bytes. But this would keep on occupying space on the server. 
The j2EE application uses MVC architecture.
I am wondering if i can apply the Filter concepts of servlets to convert tiff bytes to PDF bytes, so that i don't have to convert and store the PDF files.

NOTE: I changed the mime type from "image/tiff" to "application/pdf". I then tried 2 things:
1. Just changed the mime type to application/pdf. When i tried to download the file from client(browser) , extension was pdf but the downloaded file was corrupt.
2. Changed the mime type to application/pdf , converted the file from tiff to pdf on the server and then read the bytes from the PDF file. When i tried to download the file from the client(browser) i was able to download a PDF file which was good in all sense.

This led to the conclusion that a conversion is needed. OR maybe some header might be modified / changed when bytes are read and transmitted from tiff file. Please suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Maybe you can use pipes to stream the TIFF through `tiff2pdf` to avoid the disk usage? It is of course possible to convert in Java too (just changing the mime type won't do), but effort/difficulty depends on what information you need to get from the TIFF to the PDF.

Comment: @haraldK so using filters is not an option?

Comment: Why would it not be an option? I've done image processing and conversion in servlet `Filter`s, so I certainly think it is *possible*. I only said "just changing the mime type won't do".

Comment: @haraldK so how do i go about it?

Comment: I don't know your requirements. Neither do I fully understand what part you have trouble solving. Is it the implementation or mapping of the `Filter`, or is it the conversion from TIFF to PDF? I'd probably start by finding a suitable Java PDF library, and create a proof of concept filter using that. For the filter part, you need to intercept the bytes from the default servlet serving the TIFF file, to be able to embed it into the final PDF.